# $ \det(A B A^T - \gamma C),$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 3 $ rank $2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, tensors

Consider $A$ a $2 \times 3 $ matrix, $B$ a $3 \times 3 $ diagonal matrix with non-zero elements, and $C$ a $2 \times  2$ matrix that is also symmetric. The symmetric matrix $A A^T$ is invertible. Consider $\gamma \neq 0$.

1. Is there any way to solve the matrix equation $$ A B A^T - \gamma C=0 $$ for the matrix $B$?
2. Can I find conditions on $\gamma$ and $B$ such that $$ \det(A B A^T - \gamma C)=0?$$

So the main problem here is that the matrix $A$ is not square. I thought maybe there is a way to "complete" the matrix $A$ without messing the result of the determinant, however, I had no success with this idea.

Comment: For the first question, [vectorise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and you obtain a linear system

Comment: Due to symmetry, you have 3 linear equations in 3 unknowns

Comment: Why don't you absorb $\gamma$ into $C$?

Comment: would that help ? because we can do this.

Comment: Could you maybe try to expand your first comment about "vectorising" the equation.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ unknown?

Comment: @Youem it is. What I am aiming to find is a relation between the elements of the diagonal matrix and the $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ {\bf A} \operatorname{diag} ({\bf x}) \, {\bf A}^\top = {\bf B} $$

Let ${\bf a}_i$ denote the $i$-th column of $\bf A$.  Hence,

$$ {\bf A} \operatorname{diag} ({\bf x}) \, {\bf A}^\top = x_1 {\bf a}_1 {\bf a}_1^\top + x_2 {\bf a}_2 {\bf a}_2^\top + x_3 {\bf a}_3 {\bf a}_3^\top = {\bf B} $$

Due to symmetry, half-[vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides yields a linear system of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns

$$ \begin{bmatrix} | & | & | \\ \mbox{vech} \left( {\bf a}_1 {\bf a}_1^\top \right) & \mbox{vech} \left( {\bf a}_2 {\bf a}_2^\top \right) & \mbox{vech} \left( {\bf a}_3 {\bf a}_3^\top \right) \\  | & | & | \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} | \\ \mbox{vech} ({\bf B}) \\ | \end{bmatrix} $$